# How to use custom icon in jquery-ui 1.12 checkboxradio widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, checkbox

In jquery-ui 1.11 i could change the text with an icon using the "icons" option. That option have been depricated in v. 1.12 and replaced with "icon". But it seems that it's only possible to either use the default icon or not?

Maybe i should use another widget for this?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FlemmingH/axcdo12m/)

```
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select a Location: </legend>
    <label for="radio-1">New York</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-1">
    <label for="radio-2">Paris</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-2">
  </fieldset>

  $( function() {
    $( "#radio-1" ).checkboxradio( { icon: false} );
    $( "#radio-2" ).checkboxradio( { icon: false} );
  } );
```

Comment: Ok, theres obviously no jquery-ui solution. I added a Font Awesome solution to the fiddle: It now have to be implemented in the label class property. Since i can't find any answer on this in the jquery-ui doc's il leave this question here.

Comment: Not sure what you're loo9king for now if you are using Font Awesome.